# function to output length of longest substring possible simplification

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

so I am writing a function to output the length of the longest substring that doesn't contain a repeated character. So for example:

1. a23a8901 , will output 7 since it is 23a8901
2. a23a89a1, will output 5 since it is 23a89

so this is my solution, it works, however when super long string is being tested, the time limit exceeded. I am just wondering could someone suggest what redundancy could have been avoided in my code here:

```
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {   
    int outerMax = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
        int currentMax = 1;
        cout << "I: " << i << "\n";
        for(int j = i + 1; j < s.length() ; j++) {
            int counterInnerMax = 1;
            int noBreak = 0;
            for(int k = j ; k>i ; k--) {
                int l = k;
                while( l>i && s[k] != s[l-1] ) {
                    cout << "value of K: " << k << " then " <<  "value of l: " << l << "\n";
                    l--;
                }
            
                if(l == i) {
                    cout << "enter here at value l being: " << l << " !\n";
                    counterInnerMax++;
                    currentMax = counterInnerMax;
                    cout << "CurrentMax value: " << currentMax << "\n";
                } else {
                    noBreak = 1;
                    break;
                }
              
            }
            if(noBreak) {
                break;
            }
        }
        outerMax = max(outerMax,currentMax);
    }
    return outerMax;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it would be a better idea to use a `std::set` or an array of 256 `bool`s to track what's in a window rather than all the loops and compares. Might be able to get the time complexity down pretty close to O(N).

Comment: You should use more descriptive variable names instead of `l`, `k`, and `i`.  Your code is hard to follow as-is.

Comment: `std::unordered_set<char> set_of_chars_in_current_window;` -- Given that, how do you test if a letter is in the set of characters in the window?  One line of code `set_of_chars_in_current_window.count(letter_i_am_testing);` -- as mentioned, there is no need for a `for` loop if you were more familiar with the proper data structure to use.  It is also O(1) lookup for each character you are querying, not O(n) for each character as you're doing now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hi, could you elaborate little more? Do you mean I can write a function that would take only O(n) time complexity to solve this problem? and what data structure specifically?